# Does every SMTP server that can receive mail have to be able to send failure notices?

Tags: smtp

I am thinking about implementing my own SMTP server that can receive mail and store it. As this is a small hobby project, I'd prefer to keep the code simple – so, for example, I don't want to implement logic for sending mail. However, the following section from [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) makes me worry:

> The server must give special treatment to cases in which the
> processing following the end of mail data indication is only
> partially successful.  This could happen if, after accepting several
> recipients and the mail data, the SMTP server finds that the mail
> data could be successfully delivered to some, but not all, of the
> recipients.  In such cases, the response to the DATA command MUST be
> an OK reply.  However, the SMTP server MUST compose and send an
> "undeliverable mail" notification message to the originator of the
> message.

Does this mean that, even if I normally only return `250 OK` when I'm sure the message has been stored safely, I am forced to implement stuff for sending failure notices just in case someone decides to send a mail to both an existing and a non-existing mail address at the same time? Is there any way to get around it without violating the standard? If there isn't, how bad would it be to just send back `452 Too many recipients (my RCPT limit is 1, not 100 as required by RFC 5321)` whenever someone tries to send a mail to multiple recipients?

Comment: Well, if you want to satisfy the standard, then yes. That's why it's a standard. If not then the answer is clearly “no”.

Comment: @WaleedKhan: Well, I'd be ok with violating the standard "a little bit", or in other words, as long as it doesn't cause delivery attempts to fail. Do you think the workaround I mentioned would cause some mail servers to fail to deliver a message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-thinking the situation, I think that it's actually possible to do this in an RFC-compliant way if the server can assure that the mail can be delivered to all recipients at `RCPT` command time – after all, individual recipients can be rejected when the corresponding `RCPT` command was received. Of course, this means that the server e.g. has to ensure that enough harddisk space is available for each recipient and the maximum mail size. And a server could just deny mail to a recipient if his current mailbox size plus the maximum mail size is more than the maximum mailbox size.

Of course, the actual implementation is a bit more complicated in order to support concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

> In such cases, the response to the DATA command MUST be an OK reply.
>   However, the SMTP server MUST compose and send an "undeliverable mail"
>   notification message to the originator of the message.

That seems rather unambiguous to me.  If you are to be standards-compliant, you **MUST** both return an OK response (because the message could be delivered to some recipients) and send failure notification to the originator (because it could not be delivered to other recipients).

On the other hand, your question also mentioned that you will only accept delivery for a single recipient, so a) you've already resigned yourself to not being standards-compliant anyhow by not allowing 100 recipients and b) the failure mode of "mail data could be successfully delivered to some, but not all, of the recipients" will not be possible if there can only be a single recipient.

Comment: Only accepting delivery for a single recipient is something I might do as a workaround, not something I was planning to do anyway.

Comment: Ah, yes, re-reading the question, I see that it was only mentioned as a possible contingency plan. My mistake. Sorry about that.